# How to post on group wall?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**First, what I have:**

I have an FB app which is able to get a user's `access_token` and post on user's wall using FB API in PHP.

Can anyone please help me to 1) post on my all groups wall using a batch request (or any other technique) and 2) how to get my all groups id?

If I use my app to post on my all groups (100+) wall, is it ok with FB?
Does FB treat this as spam ?

***Thanks***

Comment: why its not get any response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Facebook batch API to post to multiple wall (groups, pages or friends wall).
The basic method to do it is shown below. The IDs can be User IDs, group IDs or Page IDs.

You can read more about it at: http://25labs.com/tutorial-post-to-multiple-facebook-wall-or-timeline-in-one-go-using-graph-api-batch-request/

```
$batchPost[] = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => "/{ID1}/feed",
    'body' => http_build_query($body) );
$batchPost[] = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => "/{ID2}/feed",
    'body' => http_build_query($body) );
$batchPost[] = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => "/{ID3}/feed",
    'body' => http_build_query($body) );

$multiPostResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
```

Comment: Sir,
I want to ask you that if i use this type of app to post on my all groups(200+) than did facebook treat this as spam ?
and what happen if i use this app for 24 or more times a day means 200 x 24 = 4800 posts a day with this app for single user is this is ok or facebook block this app or the user id

what do you suggest

thank you so much for kind corporation and favor

Answer (score 3):

i have created a facebook application 1 month back, called [WooTube](http://www.wootube.woolei.com)

To promote my application free,i joined around of 100 Groups to promote my fb video app in various of interest base like "KPOP,SNSD,SUPER JUNIOR,Just For Laught and etc" with my application build in features "Post To My Group".It is writen using fb.api
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/383568_191076937694203_922285357_n.jpg

Unfortunately this is spam...i was blocked from facebook for 2 days due to spamming.The reason is i shared the same link for around 30-40 time in less then 5-10 minutes.

what i would like to suggest is:

1. Do not share the same link for more then 20 times per day (to be safe)
2. Do not post too frequence, each post should have a space of 10 second.
3. Don't used your own account for spamming (you know what i talking about :) )